# Access Json Array from HTTP Get request and Update Page every 1s Using AJAX or JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, esp32

So, I'm working on a project which involves getting data from my website into the ESP32. I came across making the Json array and updating the info from time to time, but now I need to get the specific info from my Json array so I can use it with my ESP. For some reason when I try to access the data from my page, I'm getting 0 instead of the number that is in that place, in the case of text, I don't receive anything as a response. 
   I fixed not receiving any response from the file, I had to create a separate PHP file in which get the database info and turns that info in a datajson.json file, so the code that I have works, but I will need to update the PHP file every 1 second, I saw that Ajax was the way to go since I wouldn't need to refresh the page every time, only the content
ESP32 code:

```
void loop() {

if ((WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)) { //Check the current connection status

HTTPClient http;

http.begin("https://nps-tech.com.br/receive.php"); //Specify the URL and certificate
int httpCode = http.GET();                                                 

if (httpCode > 0)//Check for the returning code 
{ 
    String payload = http.getString();
    Serial.println("\nStatuscode: "+ String(httpCode));
    Serial.println(payload);

    char json[500];
    payload.replace(" ", "");
    payload.replace("\n", "");
    payload.trim();
    payload.remove(0,1);
    payload.toCharArray(json, 500);

    StaticJsonDocument<200> doc;
    deserializeJson(doc, json);

    int id = doc["AutoIncrement"];
    const char* nome = doc["Nome Aparelho"];
    int stat = doc["Status"];

    Serial.println(id);
    Serial.println(nome);
    Serial.println(stat);
}
else 
{
  Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
}

http.end(); //Free the resources
}

delay(10000);
}
```

New response from ESP32:

```
Statuscode: 200
[{"AutoIncrement":"1","Aparelho":"LED","Status":"0"}]
1
LED
0
```

PHP Code, How can I set a SetInterval to update get_data function from php every 1 second, without reloading the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    function get_data()
    {
        $servername = "stuuf";
        $dBUsername = "stuuf";
        $dBPassword = "stuuf";
        $dBname = "stuuf";

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBname);

        if ($conn->connect_error){
        die ("Connection failed". $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM dados;";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $json_array = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $json_array[] = array(
                'AutoIncrement'         =>       $row["AutoIncrement"],
                'Aparelho'         =>       $row["aparelho"],
                'Status'         =>       $row["Status"],
            );
        }
        return json_encode($json_array);
    }
    $file_name = 'dadosjson' . '.json';

    if (file_put_contents($file_name, get_data()))
    {
        echo $file_name. ' file created';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'There is some error';
    }
?>
<script>
    setInterval(1000);
//ajax to update every 1s
</script>
```

Comment: why no print out your php associative array as JSON then parse it without conversion in ur esp32? As advice print the GET response as json instead of associative array

Comment: How could I do that, I'm a bit lost

Comment: ok, i will help u. In your php add for example  this code: `<?php
$myArr = array("John", "Mary", "Peter", "Sally");
$myJSON = json_encode($myArr);
echo $myJSON;
?>` it will convert myArr array into json string and print it out, then in ur esp u can get the json payload using `String payload = http.getString();   //Get the request response payload
Serial.println(payload);`. and also u can convert it with the Deserialize method. Use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate the json payload.

Comment: have you understand my advice? can you post your php GET rtesponse code?

Comment: I did something different, see what you think. Instead of reading from my page. I created a php script that creates a .json file, so I can read the json file from the esp32 much easier now

Comment: I don't  undestand your solution, but i'm happy if u solve your problem. :)

Comment: Actually I may have a problem haha, Gonna try to explain better. So, I made a php code, that gets the info from my database, and the creates a data.json file inside my page. With the esp I access directly the data.json file, so the code that I have above works. But I need to refresh the page every 1s, and for some reason I can't do it

Comment: By the way the main problem in your system is that in your php response your printing an associative array instead of the json encoded version of that

Comment: If I printed the json encode (like you did on top) it will work fine?

Comment: I can only send request to the link you provide so without interact with your server-side  code it's hard give u a response. :)

Comment: Gonna paste server side so you can have a look, If you know something about javacript, so you can help me with setInterval function.

Comment: this has nothing to do with Ajax. Ajax are requests to web server done with JavaScript from web page running in browser. A GET request from esp goes to web server and the server builds the output for this one request only.

Comment: Well, if you read the other part, you will see that I will need Ajax to refresh my content  every 1 second without refresing the page

Comment: but then the esp must be a server. you will use WebServer library, not HttpClient